# Stop automatic removal of space before point when inserting `.` (dot)

Tags: text-editing

The following gif shows the behaviour quite nicely:

[image]

Whenever I type a space followed by a dot (`.`) in any mode derived from `text-mode`, emacs will replace the space with the dot. I could not want this behaviour, but couldn't figure out what causes this behaviour...

Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: Check what key `.` is bound to with `C-h k .`.

Comment: Already did. It's `self-insert-command`

Comment: Maybe you can identify suspicious active minor modes with `(mapatoms (lambda (at) (when (and (boundp at) (member at minor-mode-list) (eq (symbol-value at) t)) (message "%s" at))))`.

Comment: Check the value of `post-command-hook`.

Comment: Do you see the same thing when you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. And if it depends on what you've done interactively in your session then provide a recipe to repro the problem, starting from `emacs -Q`.

Comment: No, that animated GIF does NOT *"show the behaviour quite nicely"*. It tells us nothing about what modes are active or what you've done so far. Provide a recipe, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the culprit, it was a combination of `aggressive-fill-paragraph-mode` with `whitespace-cleanup-mode`. Setting `afp-fill-keys` to just space explicitly (used to hold space and `.` by default) fixes the problem.

```
  (setq afp-fill-keys '(?\ ))
```